# Binding values from dataTable into Specific cell in Gridview ASP c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have an existing table name [thisMonth]. I would like to bind certain values depending on the query into a specific Cell in the Gridview.

The **pseudo** goes like this * please excuse my incorrect syntax

```
sqlquery string = "Select * from [thisMonth] where [Day] = 'm1';
sqlcommand cmd = (string, con);
sqlreader read = sqlreader(cmd);
executequery;

GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text += read["value1"];
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text += read["value2"];
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text += read["value3"];
```

am I in the right path? I don't get any errors but nothing is displaying in my table.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a much easier time of it if you add an sqlDataSource to the page, set the data source of the gridView to the sqlDataSource and use your query to select data in table form for the data source.

I would go into specifics but there are plenty of other sources on Stackoverflow with examples of doing this ;)

Answer (score 0):

The default position of the `SqlDataReader` is before the first record. Therefore, you must call Read to begin accessing any data

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx

```
while (read.Read())
{
    GridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Text = read["value1"];
    GridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Text = read["value2"];
    GridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Text = read["value3"];
    rowindex++;
}

// Call Close when done reading.
read.Close();
```

Comment: the thing is, I have certain rows with specific column values that I want to be inserted to specific cell.

So let's say my row 1 is "m1 Fname Lname" and row 2 is "m2 Fname Lname"

I want all rows with m1 to be inserted to row[0]column[0]
and all rows with m2 to be inserted to row[0]column[1]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got to assign now values to specific cell but the only thing that I can't figure out is how to do endl in c# :P

here is my code now :

```
        bind.gridv = new GridView();
        bind.gridv.ID = "complete";
        bind.gridv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();

        int i = 0;
        dt.Columns.Add("m" + (i + 1) + "");

        drow[0] += "hehe\n";
        drow[0] += "haha";
        drow[0] += "hoho";
        drow[0] += "hihi";

        dt.Rows.Add(drow);

        BoundField bound = new BoundField();
        bound.DataField = "m"+(i+1)+"";
        bound.HeaderText = "m" + (i + 1) + "";

        bind.gridv.Columns.Add(bound);

        bind.gridv.DataSource = dt;
        bind.gridv.DataBind();


        this.Page.Controls.Add(bind.gridv);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(bind.gridv);
```